# Find values so matrix not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 4 & k \\
 1 & 3 & 2 \\
 3 & k & 9  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**For what values of $k$ is   the  above matrix  not invertible.**

Need help. Don't know where to start really. Thanks.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: A matrix is not invertible iff it's determinant is zero

Solve for the value of $k$ that makes the determinant $0$